# Unable to resolve service for type 'IRepository1[Play.Catalog.Service.Entities.Item]` while attempting to activate 'Controller'

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, generics

I am trying to create EF generic repository which can be shared through nuget package but I am getting following error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Play.Catalog.Interface.IRepository`1[Play.Catalog.Service.Entities.Item]' while attempting to activate 'Play.Catlog.Service.Controller.ItemsController'.
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.ThrowHelperUnableToResolveService(Type type, Type requiredBy)
   at lambda_method10(Closure, IServiceProvider, Object[])
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerFactoryProvider.<>c__DisplayClass6_0.<CreateControllerFactory>g__CreateController|0(ControllerContext controllerContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|20_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddlewareImpl.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

My files are as follows:

IEntity.cs

```cs
 public interface IEntity
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
    }
```

Item.cs

```cs
using Play.Catalog.Repositories.Interface;

namespace Play.Catalog.Service.Entities
{
    public class Item : IEntity
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
    }
}
```

CatalogDbContext.cs

```cs
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Play.Catalog.Service.Entities;

namespace Play.Catalog.Service.Db
{
    public class CatalogDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public CatalogDbContext(DbContextOptions<CatalogDbContext> options) : base(options)
        { }
        public DbSet<Item> Items { get; set; }

    }
}
```

IRepository.cs

```cs
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using Play.Catalog.Repositories.Interface;

namespace Play.Catalog.Interface
{
    public interface IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
    {
        Task<IEnumerable<TEntity>> GetALL();
        Task<TEntity?> Get(Guid id);
        IQueryable<TEntity> GetQueryable();
        void Add(TEntity item);
        void Update(TEntity item);
        void Delete(TEntity item);
        Task SaveChangesAsync();
    }
}
```

Repository.cs

```cs
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Play.Catalog.Repositories.Interface;
using Play.Catalog.Interface;

namespace Play.Catalog.Repositories
{
    public class Repository<TContext, TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity>
    where TEntity : class, IEntity
    where TContext : DbContext
    {
        private TContext _dbContext;
        public Repository(TContext dbContext)
        {
            _dbContext = dbContext;
        }
        public async Task<IEnumerable<TEntity>> GetALL()
        {
            return await _dbContext.Set<TEntity>().ToListAsync();
        }
        public async Task<TEntity?> Get(Guid id)
        {
            return await _dbContext.Set<TEntity>().FirstOrDefaultAsync(entity => entity.Id == id);
        }
        public IQueryable<TEntity> GetQueryable()
        {
            return _dbContext.Set<TEntity>();
        }
        public void Add(TEntity entity)
        {
            if (entity == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(entity));
            }
            _dbContext.Set<TEntity>().Add(entity);
        }

        public void Update(TEntity entity)
        {
            if (entity == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(entity));
            }
            _dbContext.Set<TEntity>().Update(entity);
        }
        public void Delete(TEntity entity)
        {
            if (entity == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(entity));
            }
            _dbContext.Set<TEntity>().Remove(entity);
        }

        public Task SaveChangesAsync()
        {
            return _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
        }


    }
}
```

ItemController.cs

```cs
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Play.Catalog.Interface;
using Play.Catalog.Service;
using Play.Catalog.Service.Entities;
using Play.Catlog.Service.Dtos;

namespace Play.Catlog.Service.Controller
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("items")]
    public class ItemsController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IRepository<Item> _itemRepository;
        public ItemsController(IRepository<Item> itemRepsoitory)
        {
            _itemRepository = itemRepsoitory;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IEnumerable<ItemDto>> GetAll()
        {
            return (await _itemRepository.GetALL()).Select(i => i.AsDto());
        }

        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public async Task<ItemDto> GetById(Guid id)
        {
            return (await _itemRepository.Get(id)).AsDto();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult<ItemDto>> Post(ItemDto createItemDto)
        {
            Item item = createItemDto.ToEntity();
            _itemRepository.Add(item);
            await _itemRepository.SaveChangesAsync();
            return CreatedAtAction(nameof(GetById), new { id = item.Id }, item);
        }
    }
}
```

Program.cs

```cs
using Play.Catalog.Service.Db;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Play.Catalog.Interface;
using Play.Catalog.Repositories;
using Play.Catalog.Repositories.Interface;
using Play.Catalog.Service.Entities;
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddSqlServer<CatalogDbContext>(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
builder.Services.AddScoped(typeof(IRepository<IEntity>), typeof(Repository<CatalogDbContext, IEntity>));
var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.MapControllers();
app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
app.Run();
```

Comment: It's absolutely useless to put this repository layer on top of EF's own repository (i.e. `DbSet`). Look at what it does (well, does *not*): it only adds extra methods doing nothing special. All of that can be done by accessing `DbSet`s directly.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the following line of code in your Program.cs file

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<CatalogDbContext>();
```

So your code should look like:

```
.
.
            builder.Services.AddSqlServer<CatalogDbContext>(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
            builder.Services.AddDbContext<CatalogDbContext>();
            builder.Services.AddScoped(typeof(IRepository<IEntity>), typeof(Repository<CatalogDbContext, IEntity>));
.
.
.
```

Comment: Still getting the same issue .

Answer (score 0):

You should specific the Ientity's type to let the DI know which service should be managed.

Please try below codes:

```
builder.Services.AddScoped(typeof(IRepository<Item>), typeof(Repository<ApplicationDbContext, Item>));
```

Then it will work well.

Comment: This works but for every other Entities I have add this line. I am developing generic code for repository

Comment: The thing is its impossible for generic code for repository when using DI.  Which type of the repository the DI should manage?  Which type should be registered for each controller?